# Google Pay in M2

Tags: payment-methods, magento-2.2.1

> Is there any extension available in **Magento 2** for
>   integrating Google Pay with Brian tree?

Answer (score 1):

Braintree latest version support the implementation of Google Pay through Braintree, have a look:

https://marketplace.magento.com/paypal-module-braintree.html

Comment: How should we install this extension? because the default Braintree was already installed on our site.

Comment: This module is be Gene in cooporation with Paypal and everything including installation instructions can be found here: http://support.gene.co.uk/support/solutions/articles/35000047010-how-do-i-install-the-magento-2-braintree-module-

Note: This module automatically replaces the core Braintree module.

Answer (score 0):

Official Magento 2 plugin for Google Pay is Live now !
https://marketplace.magento.com/unboundcommerce-module-googlepay.html

Comment: It's a pity we're obliged to sign up with other PSP (Adyen, Braintree, Stripe...) to get this to work. I can't understand why there isn't a «full Google Pay experience» without the need of third party partners.

Comment: @PauGNU : The link I posted above is the official google pay plugin for Magento 2.

Comment: Yes, but it says: «You will also need a merchant account with one of the following payment processors and will be subject to any transaction fees they may charge». So even if it's google official... it's also officially needing a third party PSP

Comment: The Link is now a 404. What happened to the Google Pay module in the Magento Marketplace?